# Can't get variable by POST at backend via AJAX, while it's perfectly fine at front-end

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, curl

Ok, so, here is my problem. I'm trying to send tag attribute which I store in javascript variable to backend(PHP) via AJAX.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/requests/mercury.php',
    data: {url : $(this).data('link')},
    success: function(data){
       console.log(data);
    }
```

It's a URL which I want to pass to CURL request.

CURL request is working if I write correct URL  manually, but by some reason I can't retrieve variable at backend.
I've tried debugging and it seems like I'm getting an empty array and I don't know why.

```
$link = $_POST['url'];

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://mercury.postlight.com/parser?url=".$link);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    "x-api-key: AU5zjyEqyL0LgR8zkb4Iurhlenpn52bGtbiqJA4t",
));

$x = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
```

Tried to deploy at localhost(MAMP) and Heroku, at both places same problem.

Full code is avalible at https://github.com/pjotrleshkin/RSSParsing

Comment: heroku link https://whispering-castle-73492.herokuapp.com/

Comment: cannot understand your problem. I think your code on given link is working fine.

Comment: just updated code, please, take a look

Comment: What manual url is working fine?

Comment: Inspect actual request in browser dev tools network and see exactly what is sent. We don't know what `this` is without a [mcve]

Comment: A dump of `$_POST` would be helpful also and you could see that in ajax success logging

Comment: Everything looks like it works fine on my end via the provided heroku link. The browser doesn't display an actual page currently, but the correct data was returned which can be seen in the console

Comment: added dump of $_POST at the top of the page.

Comment: example link what works perfectly fine  https://trackchanges.postlight.com/building-awesome-cms-f034344d8ed

Comment: I'm sorry, I still don't understand what exactly the issue is?

Comment: What please is $(this).data('link'). You can not use $(this) (in this form you submitted your code)

Comment: The issue is that I'm getting empty array at backend when I dump POST, when it's supposed to be a "url" variable parsed via ajax.

Comment: $ajax function is inside of $('a').click(function() { */here is posted code*/}, so i'm trying to send data-link attribute of only that <a> element which was clicked. Had I made mistake in syntax?

Answer (score 1):

Hi Pjotr Leškin there was an issue on HTTP request Methods. On your index.php the Ajax code is working fine because you are sending POST request but on link click you are opening `/requests/mercury.php` that is a GET request. So, to get the parameter on load of `/requests/mercury.php` you need $_GET['url'] and need to pass query string along with url. I have made little change on your code to handle both GET and POST request.

```
echo "<a href='requests/mercury.php' data-link = ".$item->link." target='_blank'>";
```

to

```
echo "<a href='requests/mercury.php?url={$item->link}' data-link = ".$item->link." target='_blank'>";
```

and

```
$link = $_POST['url'];
```

to

```
$link = "";

if (isset($_POST['title'])) {
    $link = $_POST['url'];
} else  {
    $link = $_GET['url'];
}
```

And I have created a pull request on your github code. Hope this will help you.